# Ext JS form file uploads file on every form submit

Tags: extjs, file-upload, submit

I am using Ext JS form file field for file upload. I need to submit form multiple times as the form will be submitted whenever `Next` button is clicked. I am using Ext JS Card Layout. The issue is every time it submits the form, the file is uploaded again. I tried disabling it and setting submitValue false but it did not work. Is there any way to upload only once?

Comment: [Yes, there's a bug in the ExtJS framework that causes the filefield to upload only once if it has no `name` attribute set.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020472/second-file-upload-fails-in-extjs-6-works-in-extjs-4/33953915#33953915)

Comment: Is it possible to you to alter the interface and handle the file upload in another form? just put up a button and call a small window to handle the upload.